# Swift function playAtTime() Does Not Add Delay

Tags: swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to play two audioPlayers, one after the other has finished playing. I'm using the Swift function playAtTime() to create a delay for the second, as follows:

```
var audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer()
var audioPlayer2 = AVAudioPlayer()

let soundPathA = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("A", ofType: "m4a")
let soundURLA = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPathA!)

let soundPathB = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("B", ofType: "m4a")
let soundURLB = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(soundPathB!)

var noteA = Sound()
noteA.URL = soundURLA

var noteB = Sound()
noteB.URL = soundURLB

self.audioPlayer1 = try!AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURLA)
self.audioPlayer2 = try!AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: soundURLB)

let duration : NSTimeInterval = audioPlayer1.duration
self.audioPlayer1.play()
self.audioPlayer2.playAtTime(duration)
```

However, no delay occurs. What is my issue here?

Comment: What is the value returned from `duration`?

Comment: That will only delay for about 0.6 seconds, is that the amount of delay you want?

Comment: Yeah, that should be the right delay, but now, the second sound is not playing at all.

Comment: can you post the rest of your code pertaining to both audioPlayers please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `playAtTime` function does not start the play at a given time. Instead it plays immediately, from the given time in the sound to be played. So if you give it 0.6, it will start playing straight away, but the sound will start from 0.6 seconds in. See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/playAtTime:).

If you want to wait before playing, you could use `dispatch_after`:

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.6 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.audioPlayer2.play()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried Michael's answer yet, but for those of you wondering how to do it with `playAtTime`, check out this: http://sandmemory.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-would-you-add-reverbecho-to-audio.html and look at the playEcho function.

The code, for me, looks like this:

```
var playTime1 : NSTimeInterval = audioPlayer2.deviceCurrentTime + (duration1*Double(value))
self.audioPlayer1.stop()
self.audioPlayer1.currentTime = 0
self.audioPlayer1.play()
```